# Wrongly displayed table, row's aren't aligned to each other

Tags: php, css

I have this issue, where I print out every detail of all users, but as you can see on the photo below, they aren't exactly aligned correctly. By that I mean that some firstnames' boxes are only let's say 50pixels wide, but some are wider.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue, and align each entry's details?
I attached the php code below, so you can have a look at it.

Thanks in advance

```
while($users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)){
        echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="80%" style="margin: 0 auto">';
        echo '<tr class="allUsers">';
        echo '<th>Username</th>';
        echo '<th>First name</th>';
        echo '<th>Last name</th>';
        echo '<th>Email</th>';
        echo '<th>Year group</th>';
        echo '<th>Subject 1</th>';
        echo '<th>Subject 2</th>';
        echo "<th>Subject 1's teacher</th>";
        echo "<th>Subject 2's teacher</th>";
        echo '<th>Privilege</th>';
        echo '<th>Own database</th>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['first_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['last_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['year_group'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['subject'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['subject2'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['teacher'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['teacher2'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['is_admin'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users['own_database'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
```

In addition to all of this, is there a way where I can just display the headers only once at the top, then just list all of the users' details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a separate table for each user, when you actually need only one. Try separating the `<table>` tags and the headers from the loop, so they are only echoed once:

```
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="80%" style="margin: 0 auto">';
echo '<tr class="allUsers">';
echo '<th>Username</th>';
echo '<th>First name</th>';
echo '<th>Last name</th>';
echo '<th>Email</th>';
echo '<th>Year group</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 1</th>';
echo '<th>Subject 2</th>';
echo "<th>Subject 1's teacher</th>";
echo "<th>Subject 2's teacher</th>";
echo '<th>Privilege</th>';
echo '<th>Own database</th>';
echo '</tr>';

while($users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUsers)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['first_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['last_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['year_group'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['subject'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['subject2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['teacher'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['teacher2'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['is_admin'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$users['own_database'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: How the hell did I not think about this! Haha:D Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like every 2 rows is its own table. Make the `<tr>`'s repeat, not the complete `<table>`'s.